# Display selected item from datagridcombobox in the next cell which is datagridtextcolumn using vb.net

Tags: sql-server, vb.net-2010

I have created a datagrid, in which there are two columns. One is datagridCombobox and another datagridtextbox column. Datagridcombobox consists of list of items. When I select an item, I want it to be displayed in the next cell ie., datagridtextbox column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a cell value changed event for the grid, in that you can get the value of combobox column value and then assign to 2nd column. hope it helps.

```
Private Sub DGV_CellValueChanged(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DGV.CellValueChanged
    Dim ComboText As String = DGV.CurrentRow.Cells(1).Value
    DGV.CurrentRow.Cells(2).Value = ComboText
End Sub
```

Comment: What is DGV_Products?

Comment: its a grid name, you can give your grid name.

Comment: What if we have multiple DatagridComboBox and datagridTextbox for each... ?

Comment: same thing you can do for that also,
 Dim ComboText As String = DGV.CurrentRow.Cells(1).Value
    DGV.CurrentRow.Cells(2).Value = ComboText
 Dim ComboText1 As String = DGV.CurrentRow.Cells(3).Value
    DGV.CurrentRow.Cells(4).Value = ComboText1
etc...

Comment: But after selecting item i have to click tab to get displayed in datagridTextbox.... Is there any method to do it automatically?

Comment: use cellvaluechanging event.

Comment: I am using SelectionChanged. CellEventChanged doesn't work